# Massive Tags Remove Using MySQL

Tags: tags, mysql

I am using **WordPress 3.4.2** for one of my site and currently it has **38,251** tags[image]

Now i want to remove all Tags from my site, so which way will be more safe to truncate every tags my site has.

Answer (score 7):

MySql `DELETE` syntax is not very different fiom `SELECT`, so you can delete from multiple tables using a single query.

Taxonomies informations in WordPress are in 3 tables:

- `wp_terms`
- `wp_term_taxonomy`
- `wp_term_relationships`

the first 2 contain term / taxonomy informations, the 3rd contains association between terms and posts.

The query to delete **all** tags from WordPress db is:

```
DELETE t, tr, tt
FROM wp_terms t  
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'post_tag'
```

Note that the prefix `wp_` can be different in your setup, it depends on `$table_prefix` setting on your `wp_config.php` file. More info [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#table_prefix).

Be sure to replace the prefix with correct value in the query for all the 3 tables.

Also note that on [**multisite**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) install, the full table name is

```
$prefix . $blogid . '_' . $tablename`
```

e.g. if the prefix is the default `'wp_'` the blog is 2, the 3 tables will be named:

- `wp_2_terms`
- `wp_2_term_relationships`
- `wp_2_term_taxonomy`

More info [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Site_Specific_Tables).

Finally, please, **be sure to have a full, valid database backup before running such a query**.

The query can be ran using a database admin tool like [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php).

Running query via php is simple in one side, because using WordPress [`$wpdb`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class, **table names are auto-resolved**, but is a harder in another side, because you have to prevent the query run multiple times, you have to check user capabilities and you need to edit php files.

Following code use a [transient](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to ensure that function run once, and also run it only when a super admin is logged in backend using [`is_super_admin()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_super_admin).

```
add_action('admin_init', function() {
  if ( ! is_super_admin() ) return;
  if ( get_transient('tags_cleaned') ) return;
  add_action( 'shutdown', 'my_clean_tags' );
});

function my_clean_tags() {
  if ( ! is_super_admin() ) return;
  if ( get_transient('tags_cleaned') ) return;
  remove_action( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
  global $wpdb;
  $q = "
  DELETE t, tr, tt
  FROM {$wpdb->terms} t  
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
  WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'post_tag'
  ";
  $result = $wpdb->query( $q );
  set_transient(' tags_cleaned', $result );
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: What about wp_termmeta table? You should include that in the query or you will have some garbage left.

Comment: @fat_mike you're right, the answer is from 2014, when term_meta table did not existed.