# Deleting All tags except categories Wp database

Tags: categories, database, tags, sql

Please Is there any way to run an SQL code to delete all post tags in wordpress except categories via database.

I want to run an sql code that will delete all my tags in wp, but not deleting my post category and posts assigned to those category.

Comment: Does this previous answer from a few years ago (and therefore slightly different WP version) work for you?... https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142252/massive-tags-remove-using-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete from `wp_terms` where `term_id` in ( SELECT `term_id`
    FROM `wp_term_taxonomy`
    WHERE `taxonomy` = 'post_tag' ) and `term_id` not like 1
```

The above Code was exactly what I was looking for.